# Is there a low-cost way to track requests from/to AWS resources?

Tags: amazon-web-services

We're interested in knowing the source and target of a request sent to or from an AWS resource, such as an RDS Instance,S3 Bucket, EC2 instance etc. The cost and level of effort are important factors we'd like to minimize so that the solution is agreeable to our managers.

We have investigated the following:

- AWS Service Map/Cloud Map - cost appears manageable, but there appears to be significant upfront effort to register/instrument services.
- AWS VPC Flow Logs - cost also appears manageable, but not all resources have VPCs associated with them. They may be extra work to map IPs to resource ARNs as well.

So far AWS Cloud Map may be the best option, but we don't know if there are other better alternates available to us. Any reccommendations would be welcome.

Answer (score 1):

It really depends exactly what your requirements are. Do you need to log the user logging in, or just the IP they're from?

If IP is sufficient I suggest that access logs are probably the cheapest and easiest method. They're definitely available for S3, should be available for software running on EC2. RDS i'm not too sure but a quick Google suggests database specific features may be able to provide something that will meet your needs.

Comment: IP is sufficient and should be enough for me to map to an ARN, given enough visibility. However, not everything has access logs. At this point would it make sense to look at joining the AWS Partner Network?

Comment: AWS Partner Network is irrelevant for this scenario. Enable access logs where available (EC2, S3, possibly RDS with database features), beyond that you will need to do some research on a per-service basis.